# In Postgres, how can I get the sub-grouping with the max value for a group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

In Postgres, I have a historical table for a subway system that has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE stop_history
(
    stop_id character varying,
    route_id character varying,
    next_stop_id character varying
);
```

I'm trying to figure out:
For a stop and route, what is the most common next stop?

What I would need to do is:
Group by stop, routes and next stop, and get the count of those groups.
For each of those groups, get the group with the highest count for each stop_id and route_id combination.

How would I write a postgres query like this, and what indexes should I place on this table to maximize performance?

One of the challenges I'm running into is not being able to use `count(*)` or `max(count(*))` in a where clause.

With sample data:

```
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('101N', '1', NULL);
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('102N', '1', '101N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('103N', '1', '102N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('104N', '1', '103N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('104N', '1', '103N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('104N', '1', '102N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('104N', '1', '103N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('104N', '1', '102N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('101N', 'D', NULL);
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('102N', 'D', '101N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('102N', 'D', '101N');
INSERT INTO stop_history VALUES ('102N', 'D', NULL);
```

Expected output is:

```
Stop | Route | Most common Next Stop | Frequency
101N 1 NULL 1
102N 1 101N 1
103N 1 102N 1
104N 1 103N 3
101N D NULL 1
102N D 101N 2
```

Comment: Use HAVING clause for aggregate function conditions!

Comment: Can you please write out a query :) ?

Comment: How does your current query look?

Comment: Please add some sample data (formatted text, please) and the expected output based on that sample data. Ideally everything as `insert` statement including the necessary `create table` statement(s)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added create and sample insert and expected output

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select distinct on (stop_id, route_id) stop_id, 
       route_id, 
       coalesce(next_stop_id, 'NULL'), 
       count(*) over (partition by route_id, stop_id, coalesce(next_stop_id, 'NULL')) as frequency
from stop_history
order by route_id, stop_id, frequency desc
```

The window function (`count(*) over (...)`) counts the frequency of the `next_stop_id` column.

The (Postgres) specific `distinct on()` is then used to reduce the result to only the ones with the highest frequency (this is achieved by the final `order by ... frequence DESC`)

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/66ff6/1